# How do I clear the memory a thread used in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, garbage-collection

I have an application in java, it connects to a database and write some reports. I want to write those reports at an specific hour every day. First I was going to use the task scheduler from windows server, but apparently it has problems executing my jar. So I though I could use a Thread in java and execute the part of my code that makes the reports as I said at an specific hour every day. This means I have to let my application running all the time, it doesn't feel right, but is my only option for the moment.

**The problem here is this:**

When I run my program, it wait till it's time to call the class that will create my reports, the problem is that at first the memory consumed by java is 11 000 KB for instance, when it executes the reports part the memory reaches almost 10 000 KB (this is reasonable I think, because I'm connecting to a database and writing files,etc.), then when it's time to write those reports again, it will get to 120 000 KB, and the next time 130 000 KB, it doesn't goes higher, but I want to know if there's a way to return to 11 000 KB once I executed the part of the reports.
I read about calling the garbage collection but it doesn't work, neither does setting to null my objects. 
Do you guys have any idea about why does this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can package it up have it run from cron daily and forget about it

Comment: Maybe you should invest more time in checking why the windows task scheduler won't run your jar. Perhaps you are trying to run it with `javaw` instead of `java`, or not setting up your paths properly. Java does not usually return unused memory to the operating system, it keeps it around for when it needs it again.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using quartz. This is a library which allows you to schedule a job that will be executed particular time with no waiting ( in a thread ) in separate thread. No reason to invent something that is invented. :) http://quartz-scheduler.org/